# Functions in main() are executing before the previous function is complete (c++ Xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, execution, timing

As the title says, I'm having problems where functions are executing before the function before them has finished. This is a problem because it's messing up the flow of my program. My main() function looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    FilePath1();
    FilePath2();

    VideoConfig1();
    VideoConfig2();

    VideoRecord();

    return 0;
}
```

and the FilePath functions look like this:

```
void FilePath1()
{
    cout << "Please enter the full filepath for where you want to save the first video: ";
    cin >> filepath1;
    cin.ignore();

}
```

The problem is that VideoConfig1() is starting directly after FilePath1(), at the same time as FilePath2(). Does anyone know why this would be happening?

I've tried using waitKey() as the initialisation of VideoConfig1(), but it had no effect.

EDIT:

The program is supposed to work as follows:

> - Run FilePath1()
>
>   - get the user to enter the filepath for video1 to be saved
> - Run Filepath2()
>
>   - get the user to enter the filepath for video2 to be saved
> - Run VideoConfig1()
> - Run VideoConfig2()
> - Run VideoRecord()

The two FilePath programs are run in the terminal, whilst the others open up their respective video windows. What the program is currently doing is this:

> - Run FilePath1()
>
>   - get the user to enter the filepath for video1 to be saved
> - Run Filepath2() AND VideoConfig1()
>
>   - get the user to enter the filepath for video2 to be saved
>   - if FilePath2 hasn't been completed by the time VideoConfig1 has, crash entire program
> - Run VideoConfig2()
> - Run VideoRecord()

Comment: Do these functions spawn any threads? What do you exactly mean by *function starts same time as*, the order in which these functions are called will not change.The processing can be affected if they spawn threads internally.

Comment: `operator>>` leaves a newline in the stream. If you're expecting it to pause, it won't.

Comment: @AlokSave No, it's all running on the one thread.

Comment: @chris I'm not sure I understand what you mean. How would this cause the two programs to run simultaneously (or near enough to simultaneously that the delay is unnoticeable)?

Comment: Could you describe the actual symptoms that have brought you to this conclusion? That is, what do you see on the screen and or hear from the speakers, and when. And exhibit `FilePath2`? (If it does the same thing as FilePath1, why don't you use one funcion and a parameter?)

Comment: Would you happen to be inputting a file path with spaces? you have left out so many details that are important to understanding exactly what is happening

Comment: @Levi Yes, there are spaces in the file path. Would using getline fix this problem?

Comment: honestly, it's been a long while since i used cin/cout, but yes, i believe so. cin will stop at the first space it encounters, so if you put in two words with a space in the middle, and press enter, the first cin will read the first word, and a second cin will read the second word and your program will just continue. getline will read the entire line, so you must use it to read a string with spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you said you are entering file paths with spaces, this is what I believe is happening:

```
FilePath1();
FilePath2();
...

void FilePath1()
{
    cout << "Please enter the full filepath for where you want to save the first video: ";
    cin >> filepath1;

    // user enters the following sans quotes: "c:\my files\file.ext"
    // filepath1 becomes "c:\my"

    cin.ignore();
    // cin.ignore() with no params will clear ONE character from the stream
    // the space is removed from the input stream

}

void FilePath2()
{
    cout << "Please enter the full filepath for where you want to save the first video: ";
    cin >> filepath2;

    // at this point, there is still data in the input buffer, 
    // so filepath2 becomes: "files\file.ext" and execution continues 
    // without waiting on user input

    cin.ignore();
    // the return is removed from the input stream, input stream is now empty

}
```

As you suggested, you want to use getline since you are expecting spaces in your input. Here's a good reference to clear up the cin vs getline: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/